# What are the pros and cons of a case statement vs a hash lookup in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What are the pros and cons of the following techniques?

**Edit**: What are the differences between the following techniques?**

I'm looking for differences related to performance, flexibility, readability, etc. Some of these things are more obvious than others.

```
class Foo
  def my_method(name)
    case name
    when "a"
      "a"
    when "b"
      "12312"
    when "c"
      "blahblah"
    when "d"
      "---------"
    when "e"
      1
    when "f"
      :reference
    end
  end
end
```

vs

```
class Foo
  MY_HASH = {
    "a" => "a",
    "b" => "12312",
    "c" => "blahblah",
    "d" => "-------",
    "e" => 1,
    "f" => :reference
  }

  def my_method(name)
    MY_HASH[name]
  end
end
```

Comment: a hash is O(1). case would be O(n) worst case. For small data sets, the case will win. for larger sets, the overhead of doing the hash calculations will be lower than the average time to do the case's repeated if/else/else/else/... testing.

Comment: Hash lookup seems to be faster in my benchmarks.

Comment: One big pro of the hash approach to remember that may become important is the flexibility. You can always dynamically add to a hash - you can't really change a case at runtime.

Comment: All good points. I'm looking for an answer that covers all of these facts. Maybe pros/cons isn't the right word so much as "differences" between the two.

Comment: The case can do a lot more than checking equality, e.g. match a regexp, Class name, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I would go with the hash constant.

Unless there's a very large number of keys, the performance **might seem** identical in both implementations.

With the hash constant however, you could simply access the constant anytime, even outside of the method you've written. You could directly view the constant (even outside the class i.e. ClassName::CONSTANT) to get all keys and values. With the case statement, accessing the keys and values will be.. trickier.

Furthermore, the hash can be easily manipulated, even dynamically, when compared to the case statement. And if you want the hash to not be changeable, simply freeze it.

```
HASH_CONSTANT = {one: 1}.freeze
HASH_CONSTANT[:one] = 1
HASH_CONSTANT[:two] #=> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash
```

One pro of the case situation would be returning a new array or hash as the default case. With

```
HASH_CONSTANT = Hash.new([]).merge(populated_hash)
```

The same array would be returned with any key that isn't present in the hash.

```
# :a and :b are non-existent keys
value_a = HASH_CONSTANT[:a] #=> []
value_a << 1
value_b = HASH_CONSTANT[:b] #=> [1]
```

However when you will return an empty array in the case's "else" condition, a new array will be returned. This can be beneficial, depending on your particular usage.

But then again, you could always do:

```
HASH_CONSTANT = populated_hash
HASH_CONSTANT[non_existent_key] || []
```

Comment: As you have already answered, let me add something: you can check for an object's class: `a=42;

case a;
when Numeric;
p :Number;
end;` (which is equivalent of if: `p :Number if Numeric===a;` as fair I remember). With hash you could use something like: `h={Fixnum => :Number}; p h[a.class]`.

Comment: A `case` statement can be used out side the scope it was defined if you want to. In fact you can build your own dynamic `case` statement, though not a wise decision. I've written a simple example for you to see or run here: http://pastebin.com/9sqBG0Xa .

Answer (score 3):

From a runtime performance perspective, the switch statement will take O(N) time whereas the hash statement will take O(1) time. This is because the switch statement will force the runtime to iterate through each option down the list before finding the condition that matches. This probably isn't a very important distinction unless you are doing a LOT of lookups.

From a security perspective, the hash table could be compromised by overwriting an existing entry. On the same note, the hash table allows for greater flexibility by being able to map new items at runtime.

From an cleanliness perspective, using a hash table is cleaner if you will have a lot of entries to process. Once you get past 10, 20, 30 switch statements, things could start getting pretty gnarly.

Comment: O(N) is **preferable** over O(n). (Capital N) :)